# PrimeVue DataTable Row Color based off of Column Item

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, datatable, primevue

So I have a PrimeVue DataTable that is structured like so:

```
<DataTable value="info">
  <Column header="Name" field="name" />
  <Column header="Desc." field="desc" />
  <Column header="Date" field="date" />
</DataTable>
```

The value of the DataTable is occupied by the array, "info", which consists of information pulled from an API. I need certain rows within the DataTable to appear either red or green based on the property "desc" within "info"; I have attempted to go about it in these ways:

**Using rowStyle**

```
<DataTable value="info" :rowStyle="desc === 'Disconnected' ? 'color:red' : null">
  <Column header="Name" field="name" />
  <Column header="Desc." field="desc" />
  <Column header="Date" field="date" />
</DataTable>
```

I have used multiple variations of rowStyle, but the primary issue I am having is accessing variables within the DataTable when implementing said style. I suppose another method could be using a ColumnGroup and then assigning a `<Row>` value, then modifying it with the respective color change?

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you provide a function to `:rowStyle` or `:rowClass`, the first argument is row's `data`, which you can use to decide the color.

```html
<DataTable :rowClass="({ desc }) => desc === 'Disconnected' ? 'text-red-500': null">
  ...
</DataTable>
```

Similarly, inside a `<Column>`'s `#body` slot, you will find `data` and `field` properties, which can be used to decide the color:

```html
<Column field="desc" header="Desc.">
  <template #body="{ field, data }">
    <div :class="data[field] === 'Disconnected' ? 'text-red-500' : null">
      {{ data[field] }}
    </div>
  </template>
</Column>
```

[Docs example](https://primefaces.org/primevue/datatable/style).

You might want to write the function inside `<script>` and reference it in template, as shown in the example, instead of writing it inline, as I did above. Both work.

Comment: Yeah, can't seem to get any of these methods to work; the most optimal method would be the first one, as it needs to change the entirety of the row's color to red, but even changing it from row-class to row-style/rowStyle, it doesn't want to work?

Comment: The only way I can be of more help would be if you showed me what you're trying. Note you can [export](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your local project to a sandbox.